# How to establish Connection in Routes

Tags: routes, jms, tibco, ems, tmb

I want to create a route between two tibco EMS Server. But I am not getting the connection ID. It says Status = Not Connected.

I have done the below changes:

```
       Step-1 : Enable the routing feature in tibemds.conf
                 routing  = enabled

       Step-2 : Connect tibco admin portal and run the below command:

                 create route [SERVERB_NAME] url=ssl://SERVERB-URL:7243 zone_name=Z1 
                 zone_type=1hop

                  Command outupt : Route '[SERVERB_NAME]' to 'ssl://SERVERB-URL:7243' has been added

       Step-3 : show route ROUTE-NAME
                ssl://localhost:7243> show route SERVERB_NAME
                Route                       = SERVERB_NAME
                URL                         = ssl://SERVER-URL:7243
                Zone Type                   = 1hop
                Zone Name                   = Z1
                Config                      = Present in local configuration
                Status                      = Not connected
```

Can any one help me to understand.. what I am missing...

Answer (score 0):

After more debug i got the issue and able to get connection Id under ConnId column.

I have use **ssl_verify_host = disabled** into routes.conf file. The issue was ssl verification getting failed while trying to create route. So either copy SSL Certificate of SERVERB into SERVERA or simply disabled ssl verification.

After change routes.conf file looks like :

```
[SERVERB_NAME]
 url   = ssl://SERVERB-URL:7243
 ssl_verify_host = disabled
```

When routes created successfully, its look like :

```
 ssl://localhost:7243> show route SERVERB_NAME
 Route                       = SERVERB_NAME
 URL                         = ssl://SERVERB-URL:7243
 Zone Type                   = mhop
 Zone Name                   = default_mhop_zone
 Config                      = Present in local configuration
 Status                      = Connected,  id=2
 Backlog                     = count=0, size=0.0 Kb
 ssl_verify_host             = disabled
```